# I want to re-position the badge graphics on a tab control

Tags: iphone, xcode, layout, badge, uitabcontroller

Does anyone know how to re-position the badges on a UITabController?  I'm using custom graphics and the badge graphic have the right edge cut off.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: create your custom badge graphics then. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to overlay the old ones?